# Adding waypoints to navigate in waze map

Tags: android, navigation, waze

In my application i want implement waze map navigation for multiple destination,i just achieved single origin and destination navigation ,but here i want to navigation multiple waypoints.

```
     String url = String.format("waze://?ll=" + Double.parseDouble(_Lat) + "," + Double.parseDouble(_Long) + "&navigate=yes");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a solution to the exact same problem.
Looks like they don't wish to provide - clueless why they are afraid people would use that.

Anyway, would it be possible that the activity which opened the intent also has a simple GPS listener which calculates when you're (almost) reached (or passed) your waypoint, and set the next coordinates (in the opened intent / or new one) ...?

For now I'm using google maps with a full URL, still I wish to send my users straight into navigation, not a browserwindow that may have or may not have a navigation button (Chrome versus other browsers).

A simple A to B is not working for me, I need a "A B C, break, C B A".